# MVC Naviagtion Failure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using asp.net MVC and I have one link that is behaving oddly.
My system has a page for holidays

> http://localhost:53713/Holidays

On this page there are a number of links to show records, all fine.
But I have a link to book a new holiday

```
<a asp-action="Book" class="pull-right">
            <span class="label alert-cascade"><u>Book a New Holiday</u></span>
        </a>
```

The link results in the url:

> http://localhost:53713/Holidays/Book

If I click it, it will sit forever, just with the small loading icon and seemingly does nothing.
If I copy the link into the browser url and navigate that way it then works, and after that the normal link also works for the duration of the session.

This is the only link in my project that is doing this.
I've tried changing the link to a simply href and it does the same.

Why on earth would this happen?? I even reduced the content of the page to nothing and it still has the issue..

Comment: have you tried using asp-controller attribute? try this asp-controller="Holidays". if it works i will post this solution as answer

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I had high hopes but sadly it still just sits there loading.. forever. Just putting the url in and hitting enter works fine so Im lost on what this thinks its doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a javascript exception message on the page.. MVC sits loading forever if the page its loading has a javascript error but directly navigating to the page in the browser makes it ok?>??